# SplashRequest - Cannot get data attribute

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm strugling to find out why I receive error:

> AttributeError: 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'data'

**From documentation:**

```
SplashJsonResponse provide extra features:

response.data attribute contains response data decoded from JSON; you can access it like response.data['html'].
```

**Here is my sample code:**

```
class HeadphonesSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "headphones"
    handle_httpstatus_list = [404]

    def start_requests(self):
        splash_args = {
            'html': 1,
            'png': 1,
            'width': 600,
            'render_all': 1,
        }
        yield SplashRequest('https://domain.tld', self.parse_result, endpoint='render.json', args=splash_args)

    def parse_result(self, response): 
        title = response.css('title').extract_first()
        print(title)
        png_bytes = base64.b64decode(response.data['png'])
        #... rest of the processing
```

Splash rendering server is running on http://0.0.0.0:8050/ and I can receive data from it when I issue `curl` command from console.

Comment: Looking at the scrapy docs [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#response-objects), I do not see a `data` attribute in instances of `Response`. Is `body` what you are looking for?

Comment: @JamesMchugh It's `Response` from Splash but not from Scrapy.

Comment: I see that, but its a `HTMLResponse` object that is causing the `AttributeError`, so you might not be getting the `SplashJsonResponse` object that you expected.