# Scrapy Splash AttributeError: 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'data'

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I have a simple scrapy spider that has to create a screenshot. Below is my code and I am getting the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxx\scrapy_screenshot\scrapy_screenshot\spiders\extract.py", line 19, in parse_result
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(response.data['png'])
AttributeError: 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'data'

```
import json
import base64
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class ExtractSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'extract'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
        splash_args = {
            'html': 1,
            'png': 1
        }
        yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse_result, endpoint='render.json', args=splash_args)

    def parse_result(self, response):
        imgdata = base64.b64decode(response.data['png'])
        filename = 'some_image.png'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(imgdata)
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/59011139/939364

Comment: But this link doesn't have an answer also

Comment: As per a deleted link-only answer: Solved this by configuring settings.py as described in this link https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash

Comment: Does anyone have a working solution? I configured the settings exactly like in the link of @TrentonMcKinney, but it still does return a simple HtmlResponse without a data object despite the endpoint being "render.json".

Comment: @Lebbers I have run into soo many problems with Scrapy-Splash that I am convinced the library is broken and the docs don't reflect its current capabilities or lack thereof. I configured everything as described in the docs and still hitting issue after issue I am considering switching to Selenium even though its slower. At least then I'll have some results.

Answer (score 0):

For me issue was that settings.py didn't affect enabled middleware's, so adding settings directly to spider helped.

```
import json
import base64
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class ExtractSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'extract'
    custom_settings = {
        "SPLASH_URL": "http://localhost:8050",
        "DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES": {
            "scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware": 723,
            "scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware": 725,
            "scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware": 810,
        },
        # Enable Splash Deduplicate Args Filter
        "SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES": {
            "scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware": 100,
        },
        # Define the Splash DupeFilter
        "DUPEFILTER_CLASS": "scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter",
        "HTTPCACHE_STORAGE": "scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage",
    }
    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
        splash_args = {
            'html': 1,
            'png': 1
        }
        yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse_result, endpoint='render.json', args=splash_args)

    def parse_result(self, response):
        imgdata = base64.b64decode(response.data['png'])
        filename = 'some_image.png'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(imgdata)
```